# Simple program using Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I got homework to create a program using Tasks.

The program should generate 100,000 numbers in the range from 100,000 to 100,000,000 
Then check whether the number is a prime number and if that number is Fibonacci number.

There are strict requirements for this program:

1) The first task should generate the number.

2) Second task should check if the number is prime.

3) The third task should check if the number is fibonacci.

!! Only after the third action program should generate a new number. !!

I have written a program, but it takes a very long time before all the numbers is generated. What I'm doing wrong? Is there any other way to do it faster ? Because it takes about 25 minutes to generate all the numbers. (I'm using MS VStudio 2010, Framework 4)

Sorry for my English..

Code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {

            Task<int> t1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => RandomGen1.Next()); // Generate Number
            Task<string> t2 = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => is_prime(t1.Result)); // Return Yes or No
            Task<string> t3 = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => IsFibonacci(t1.Result)); // Return Yes or No

            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {t1,t2,t3});

            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(t1.Result, t2.Result, t3.Result); 

        }
```

Update:

Here's my is_prime and isFibonacci functions:

```
public string is_prime(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return "Yes";
    }

    static string IsFibonacci(int number)
    {

        double fi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2.0; //Golden ratio
        int n = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(number * Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5, fi)); //Find's the index (n) of the given number in the fibonacci sequence

        int actualFibonacciNumber = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Pow(fi, n) / Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5); //Finds the actual number corresponding to given index (n)

        if (actualFibonacciNumber == number)
        {
            return "Yes";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote for the question. It is clear, includes the relevant code, and shows effort.

Comment: It's starting up and closing down the 3 tasks 100000 times. This will be slow. Also, it's adding to a WPF grid one row at a time, which is also not optimal. Try narrowing down the problem by commenting out different bits of code, and checking the performance. You should get a good idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: Why the RandomGen1.Next?

Comment: I found that class on the internet:                          public static class RandomGen1
    {
        private static Random _inst = new Random();

        public static int Next(){
            lock (_inst) return _inst.Next(100000,100000000);
        }

    }

Comment: Okay this could be your performance issue. Try to generate the random numbers in a serperate step, and put them into a array/list and work with this list.

Comment: I can't generate all numbers and put them into array, because first i need to check generated number with functions is_prime and isFibonacci only then i can generate a new number. It's requirements.

Comment: Totally strange requirements for practicing tasks, there seems to be nolid reason for using tasks int the first place, since you arnt doing anything asychronous and wait everytime for all of them to complete.

Comment: Are you sure that your test methods `is_prime` and `IsFibonacci` aren't just horribly slow? Try commenting out the `Rows.Add()` and see if it is still so slow.

Comment: Start with small intervalls, for example 10 to 100 and check the results. If the results are correct, then increase the intervall. And since the tasks are depending on each other, you can just use `Task.ContinueWith` to *connect* the next task input with the previous task result.

Comment: Just change that random numbers function to: `Random rnd = new Random(); public int generate(){int num = rnd.Next(10,100); return num;}` and it generated in 3 min.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't usually do homework for people, I found this a nice problem to solve, and I had a some code laying around from solving Project Euler questions that I could put to use.

I agree with one of the comments that this is a strange requirement to use to Tasks for, seems to be using Tasks for just for the sake of it.

The console app I put together runs in about 15 seconds. No, I'm not going to post the code, because you won't learn anything.

Without seeing the code behind your `is_prime` and `IsFibonacci` methods, it's hard to say what could be wrong. I hope you aren't doing something silly like calculating a list of all the fibonacci numbers up to the random number on each iteration through the loop, as that is going to be dreadfully slow.

Remember: [A number is Fibonacci if and only if one or both of (5*n2 + 4) or (5*n2 – 4) is a perfect square.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers)